# How should I repair a damaged brick post base?

Tags: brick, beam, cement

I recently moved into a house with a garage. One of the posts looked off and it’s because it was pushed inside as the edge bricks had cracked off.

[image: garage]

[image: broken bricks]

I have 0 experience with bricks,  but I am wondering if I can fill the corner with cement using wood to mold it and hold it until it dries. Once solid, I would then use a mallet to push the post back.

[image: not damaged]

Am I thinking this correctly. What should I do (is there also a type of cement I should buy)

Comment: It'd help to see what the post is supporting, and how.

Comment: Welcome. Please take the [tour] so you know how this site works. "Thanks" comments are discouraged.

Answer (score 1):

You could form and pour concrete, but it would look terrible. It would stand out like a sore thumb, screaming "lazy".

Find some compatible bricks (look for free used ones) and mortar them in properly. There's plenty of information to be found on how to do that, and it's not at all difficult. You'll be proud of the outcome instead of embarrassed by it.

- [What type of mortar should I use?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/q/25639/35141)
- [How do I fix a loose brick on the corner of a tree well?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/q/68000/35141)

Make sure you keep support in place during the work, unless you can verify that the posts are merely decorative. A longer board resting on the slab should do, as long as you secure it so it can't slip out.

Answer (score 0):

I would do the following:

1. fit a clamp around the post to provide a jacking point
2. arrange some support either side and then jack up to provide a small amount of clearance
3. repair the bricks appropriately,
4. once set then lower the post back onto the new bricks.

Consideration may need to be given to the damage and to making sure moisture / rain flows off so the post end does not rot - it does show signs of damage due to being forced sideways.

Answer (score 0):

Posts like these should have some sort of bracket supports so that a wheel barrow or something doesn't accidentally bump them off of their foundations. By my estimation, then, this job will require two rotohammer rentals, where instead you might buy a cheap rotohammer (my current one was 90 USD at Harbor Freight somewhat recently). Get a rotohammer and a chisel bit for it.

To get the post out of your way, you'll want to hammer it away from the opening further. Start moving it, however, and it might unstably run, especially with subsequent vibration from the chiseling. Before hammering the post out of the way, then, cut a chunk of 2×4 or 4×4 to lay on its side at the end of that existing 2×4 to the left of your post's base. Make it about 6" shorter than the current gap. Hammer the post base over to it to give yourself room to work, where you'll want a chunk of scrap wood between the hammer and the post to avoid disfiguring the post's material.

Now use the rotohammer and chisel bit to remove the brick fragments, and chisel away the old mortar to expose whole bricks for building upon. @isherwood's links look well selected for installing replacement brick.

Once the new brick and mortar have had 3 days of curing, it should be okay to restore the post. I would be nervous to just hammer it right up to the edge again, fearing that it might snag on the brick and break something, but I'm not there to feel how much resistance it has when hammering it back into position. Try it. If it moves pretty easily, then don't be nervous. If you're not sure, then a 2×4 up to right beside the post's top bearing point can be combined with a bottle jack to unload the post and thereby facilitate positioning.

For anchoring the posts in position, shop around the hardware store for thick L-shaped metal brackets with fabricated holes. Just one bracket per post is fine. Hot dip galvanized or "z-max" brackets would be ideal. Install them to look pretty. For anchoring in brick use sleeve anchors (you'll have to buy a rotohammer bit suited to the sleeve anchors). For attaching to the posts, hot dip galvanized lag screws are probably what you want.

Comment: Thank you. I will need to put clamps down to secure it. I’ll need to look into the rotohammer